# PostSharp undo/redo и System.Windows.Media.Color

Tags: c#, wpf, aop, postsharp

Я использую PostSharp для реализации Undo/Redo над моделью.

Есть класс

```
[Recordable] 
class MyClass 
{
  [Child]
  public System.Windows.Media.Color TextColor { get; set; }
}
```

При попытке билда возникают ошибки:

> 1) Error  1   The type of MyClass.k__BackingField is a value
>   type that can contain a reference to a reference type. The
>   [Aggregatable] aspect requires this type to implement IAttachable
>   manually.
>
> 2) Error  2   The type of field MyClass.k__BackingField is not
>   compatible with the [Recordable] aspect: mutable value types are not
>   allowed.

Как я понял ошибка говорит о том, что `System.Windows.Media.Color` содержит `ColorContext`, который является объектом класса (reference type). Как это можно обойти? Может есть какие-то дополнительные атрибуты? В документации PostSharp ничего по этой ошибке найти не смог.

Answer (score 1):

Все классы в дереве (кроме базовых, типа `int`, `bool`, `string` и проч.) [должны быть помечены атрибутом `Recordable`](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/New-in-PostSharp-32-UndoRedo) (см. раздел Object Graphs and Collections). Отсюда приходит вариант -- разложите хранение цвета на несколько составляющих, оставив те, которые у вас используются. Используйте этот новый класс в исходном классе. При этом вам где-то нужно будет дополнительно вызывать конверсию из/в `System.Windows.Media.Color`.

```
[Recordable] 
class MyClass 
{
    [Child]
    public RecordableColor TextColor { get; set; }
}

[Recordable] 
class RecordableColor 
{
    public byte R { get; set; }

    public byte G { get; set; }

    public byte B { get; set; }

    public Color GetColor()
    {
        return Color.FromRGB(R, G, B);
    }

    public void SetColor(Color color)
    {
        R = color.R;
        G = color.G;
        B = color.B;
    }
}
```